# How to rollback or not commit with sql loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using sql loader to charge data files to tables. I dont know if it commit at each row (would not be good) or at the end of file.

Anyway, I try to discover if there is a possibility of rollback if any error occurs. Rollback or no commit;

I tried different things :

```
- the "errors = 0" parameter but whatever is good is committed
- the "rows = 99999" parameter but it is committed anyway
- the "rows = 99999 errors = 0" parameters but the commit is still there.
```

Any solution ?

Thanks

definition of error : some bad file or discard file exists

version : SQL*LOADER : release 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: What version of sqlldr are you using?

Comment: You can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634932/how-to-rollback-when-an-error-occurs-while-executing-sql-loader-command. Alex's answer has some good suggestions for alternatives.

Comment: What is your definition of error?  If any constraints or design are violated (PK, NOT NULLs, invalid datatype, etc.) it will automatically reject that row, but commit the rest.  You have BADFILE and DISCARDFILE parameters so that you can see what was rejected and why.  Also, my general approach when using sqlldr is to not insert directly into the base/transactional table, but into a staging table so that you have more control over the data quality.